# Is there a way to check if a model field has been fetched?

Tags: python, peewee

Let's say I have a User model, which has a foreign key pointing to Usertype.

If I simply retrieve my User without joining the Usertype table, there will be an extra query to retrieve that Usertype when I finally access it.

My question is if there is a way to check if such field is already filled, or if my access will trigger a fetch.

Something like this:

```
class Usertype(BaseModel):
    name = CharField(max_length=32)

    def serializable(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name
        }

class User(BaseModel):
    name = CharField(max_length=32)
    usertype = ForeignKeyField(Usertype)

    def serializable(self):
        ret = {
            'name': self.name,
        }

        if self.usertype:
            ret['usertype'] = self.usertype.serializable()

        return ret
```

If I do it like this, my assumption is that the if statement will cause that fetch to happen.

**Update:**

From Taras answer I was able to figure out that there is a _obj_cache property on models, that holds the cached related objects.
So I can achieve what I want with:

```
def serializable(self):
    ret = {
        'name': self.name,
    }

    if 'usertype' in self._obj_cache:
        ret['usertype'] = self.usertype.serializable()

    return ret
```

However, this doesn't look like a great approach, messing with internal fields.

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically - yes, there is way, but not the one you want to choose. 
I was digging through the code and found the place where data is cached. If you check line [#382](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b8741c005873396de24a085fe9ab13d2348a306b/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L382) you will see next code:

```
# The related instance is loaded from the database and then cached in
# the attribute defined in self.cache_name. It can also be pre-cached
# by the forward accessor (ForwardManyToOneDescriptor).
try:
    rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)
except AttributeError:
    related_pk = instance._get_pk_val()
```

What is says is 'I am going to get value from database unless it exists in the cache. What is the name of the cache? - in your case it is `u'_usertype_cache'`. Here is a proof:
[image]

So, technically - yes, there is a way. Do you really want to use protected fields and add your own hacks? I would not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was trying to see if that would work and apparently in the Peewee version I have, it doesn't work exactly like that. It seems there is a _obj_cache dictionary in each model, which holds that cache. So I'm able to do "if 'usertype' in user._obj_cache:".

Comment: I do agree it's not pretty and likely subject to change. I'll wait to see if coleifer can provide a more supported approach.